# Do count(*) for each table which comes as output of another select

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to use output of `select` as input of another.

Select 1 - `select table_name from tables;` - this gives 15 tables.

Select 2 - I want to do a count row `count (*)` for each table.

I tried doing `select count(*) from (select table_name from tables) as derived_table;` but I get 1 row with value 15 (which is the table count). How can I do count for each table?

Answer (score 0):

SQL generating SQL. The "report" of the first SELECT is the script to run at the end.
Using "vsql", Vertica's default SQL client (free download from my.vertica.com) ...

```
--tuples only
\t
-- unaligned output
\a
-- pipe the output through yet another vsql session
\o |vsql
SELECT
  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name)
    WHEN 1 THEN ''
    ELSE 'UNION ALL '
  END
||'SELECT '||QUOTE_LITERAL(table_name)||'AS tbname,COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM '||table_name
FROM tables 
WHERE table_schema='public'
;

# test run:
$ vsql -f countpublic.sql
Showing only tuples.
Output format is unaligned.
     tbname      | rowcount
-----------------+----------
 KOMM            |        8
 canary          |        6
 canary_v        |      666
 certificates    |        6
 change_stream   |        6
 conc            |  1503511
 conc_ext        |  1503511
 d_oppty_scd     |        8
 d_product       |        4
 date_dim        |    73049
(10 rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName],
[Tables].name AS [TableName],
SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
-- WHERE [Tables].name = N'name of the table'
GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), [Tables].name;
```

Comment: This is SQL Server; Seems to be about Vertica, though ...